# How to understand the program

Tags: c, linux

```
int mask = 0700, N_BITS = 3;
struct stat buff;
static char perm[] = {"---", "--x", "-w-", "-w x", "r--", "r-x", "rw-", "rwx"};
stat(f_d, &buff); //get the permissions info of file
printf("%3s", perm[buff.st_mode & mask >> (i - 1) * N_BITS)] //HOW TO UNDERSTAND ?`
mask >>= N_BITS; //HOW TO UNDERSTAND ?
```

Comment: sounds like homework... you are supposed to describe what the program does? this site is not here for such problems. you should give more info, say what you think it does, where and what exactly you don't understand, and so on. most importantly, you should probably follow some C tutorials first.

Answer (score 1):

`>>` is the bitwise right shift operator.

```
X >>= N
```

is equivalent to

```
X = X >> N
```

Some examples:

- (4 >> 1) = (0100b >> 1) = 0010b = 2
- (12 >> 2) = (1100b >> 2) = 0011b = 3

Answer (score 1):

`>>` is the [bitwise right shift operator](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-bitwise-right-shift/)

`mask>>=N_BITS` is equivalent to `mask = mask >> N_BITS`

So initially

```
mask = 0b111000000;
```

As `N_BITS` equals **3** after `mask>>=N_BITS` operation

```
 mask = 0b000111000;
```